# DateTime Format from View to Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm developing an app for French speakers for which the normal way to write a date is something like dd-MM-yyyy or yyyy-MM-dd. Is there a way to say that to the model to bind another format of date? Right now, the system switches the month and the day or returns null if the day (which becomes the month) is ­>12.
Thanks

Comment: The culture on your server must match the format that your posting, or you need to create a custom ModelBinder to convert the value to the server culture. But note that if the value is posted in ISO format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) it will always be bound correctly irrespective of the server culture

Comment: Wow, thanks. That's what I did :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Submitting details from ui try to submit in required format. (formatting the datetime available in all calendar plugin)

And Create a custom culture like this to force back end (asp.net ) to always use required format.

Inlcude this code in global.asax.cs

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) // Customizing / Intializing DateTime Format to yyyy/MM/dd to avoid conflicts 
    {
        CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect that you can have a date in one of multiple formats, then bind it to the model as string, define its format on the controller side, and convert to DateTime.

Comment: Both answers are useful, but I'll use the cultureInfo one since it'll modify all the apps date formats instead of just one occurence. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Terrible advice!